# DHCP not enabled in cmd Ipconfig /all despite having an active DCHP server

Tags: dhcp

This is really weird. So I have a DHCP server running and working on my Member server in win2008 but when i run ipconfig /all in cmd it says DHCP not enabled. Also, BGinfo says i dont have a DHCP. I checked my DHCP and it is running and servicing clients.

Does anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds to me like you're trying to run a DHCP server on a computer, but the places you're describing looking at relate to the *DHCP client* on that machine. A DHCP server computer will have a static IP address assigned, and, as such, `ipconfig /all` *will* show that DHCP is disabled.  Read the words "Dhcp Enabled" there as "DHCP client enabled" and it'll make more sense.

As a quick-and-dirty test, you should trying leasing an IP address from the DHCP server from another computer on the local network with the DHCP server computer. The DHCP management console snap-in and the event log are also great places to see the operational status of the DHCP server. Be sure that the DHCP server is "authorized" to operate in your Active Directory domain (see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754493.aspx for details).

Comment: ah thanks, i just realized that it says "no" because i have a static ip on my server